# Why will xcode not update?

Tags: xcode, macos

So I ran brew doctor to fix something else, and noticed xcode was out of date. I went to app store to update it, and it was updated. So I checked the xcode app version. And it was still the older version. So I did a reboot several times. Still out of date. I searched through the xcode app for updating. Came up empty handed. Googled around and still can't find anything. I'm not sure what other context I can give that the attached image doesn't already give you. Any thoughts?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AppStore image shows Command Line Tools for Xcode, not Xcode itself. Personally, I always install Xcode from the Apple Developer Member Centre so I can download beta versions if wanted.

Comment: Ah, ok, missed that obvious detail, thanks. Though I do have a question maybe you can help me better understand. So the last sentence in the Xcode command line tools it says "If you use Xcode, these tools are also embedded within the Xcode IDE". So if I have Xcode 8.0 (which has these command line tools in it) and I have Xcode Command Line Tools 8.2 installed. Which one is my bash session actually using? Brew doctor seems to think it's 8.0. Just want a better understanding of how this works.

Comment: According to the homebrew docs "Most formulae require a compiler. A handful require a full Xcode installation. You can install Xcode, the CLT, or both" but in your case it sounds like homebrew is preferring the full Xcode installation. If you use Xcode I would go with that, otherwise remove it!

Comment: I see. Thanks @Mark Brownsword